# Facing problem in uploading image returned from cv2.imdecode()

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to upload the image returned by cv2.imdecode on cloudinary but I  am gettin this error.

```
 The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

My code goes like this -

```
def url_to_image(url):
    # download the image, convert it to a NumPy array, and then read
    # it into OpenCV format
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cloudinary_response = cloudinary.uploader.upload(image)
    return cloudinary_response
```

It gives error in cloudinary.uploader.upload line. I am unable to understand the return type of cv2.imdecode(), and can it be uploaded to image servers like S3 BUCKET or cloudinary.

```
Traceback - 

ValueError at /api/v1/users/getstyledimages
The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
 ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Request Method: POST
Request URL: 
https://rhymella.mobikasa.net/api/v1/users/getstyledimages
Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Executable: /var/www/rhymella/rhymella/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path: ['/var/www/rhymella', 
'/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python35.zip', 
'/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5', 
'/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
'/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
'/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site-packages', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/']
Server time: Tue, 16 Oct 2018 15:58:09 +0000
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'api',
 'cloudinary',
'newadmin']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
128.                 response = 
self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, 
*callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
494.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
454.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

 File "/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
 491.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/rest_framework/decorators.py" in handler
 53.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/rhymella/api/views.py" in get_styled_images
 6818.             res = 
 style.add_artistic_style(each.styled_images)

 File "/var/www/rhymella/filters/style.py" in add_artistic_style
 21.     cloudinary_response = cloudinary.uploader.upload(img)

 File "/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/cloudinary/uploader.py" in upload
 40.     return call_api("upload", params, file=file, **options)

 File "/var/www/rhymella/rhymella/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/cloudinary/uploader.py" in call_api
 269.         if file:
```

Comment: You never define `img`. This should give you a NameError. Please check your code, and make sure the code in your question is the same code you actually run. Also include the full traceback for the error. The traceback contains essential information for diagnosing errors.

Comment: @HåkenLid I am getting value error

Comment: In the cloudinary.uploader line you use a variable name called `img`. So either this is not the code you run, or the error is caused in a previous line.

Comment: @HåkenLid  Thats By mistake. added traceback as well. Please suggest now

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an incorrect type here. `upload` does not accept a numpy array. cv2 images are numpy.ndarray objects.

```
cloudinary_response = cloudinary.uploader.upload(image)
```

The argument can be a string which is the path of a local file, or it could be a url. This would work, for example.

```
def url_to_image(url):
    return cloudinary.uploader.upload(url)
```

Consult the [cloudinary docs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images) for other options. If you want to convert your image to a numpy array, you have to encode it back to some valid type before passing it to cloudinary.uploader.

Comment: I have to carry cv2 operations on the image before uploading it to cloudinary

Comment: Fine. Just convert it to a image file and upload it after the processing. This is already covered in my answer. You can use `cv2.imwrite()` to save the numpy array as an image file.